# `Illegal unquoted character` error with the Azure CosmosDB Connector

Tags: ballerina

I'm running into an issue with the CosmosDB connector. Specifically, when using the `replaceDocument` function with a document that contains a JSON-unfriendly string (eg: "testing\n123"), it fails with an error from Azure.

This error is being surfaced despite calling `.toJson()` on the parent document, which should handle all of the string conversions correctly.

The error I get from the Cosmos API is error: `Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10))`

Answer (score 1):

The issue with JSON-unfriendly string can be resolved by escaping the special characters such as `\n`.

Optionally, you can Base64 encode the specific data and insert it in the document or if the JSON-unfriendly string is large we can go to an option like storing the string in a separate attachment and refer it in the document.

- We cannot replace the `id` as per the current implementation of the connector.
- The option to replace the `_etag` is also not supported as per the current implementation of the connector.

These features will be added in a future version of the connector

But note that `_etag` values are automatically generated by Cosmos DB and is used for optimistic concurrency control. If we're manually replacing the `_etag` value, make sure you're aware of the implications and consider using the appropriate concurrency control mechanisms provided by Cosmos DB to handle conflicts.